# why are my google adsense ads create errors in inspect console?

Tags: adsense

my page had no errors, no messages, no issues. I turned ad-blocker off.   I added the auto adsense code from Google:

*Let Google place ads for you
Add one piece of code to your site and Google will automatically show ads in all the best places.*

The ads don't appear.

console says there are 5 errors now.

My html is skeletal. No js, no css. What is the problem with the snippet of Google javascript I added?

thanks,

Alex

Below, new errors raised from adding google adsense snippet:

```
zrt_lookup.html?fsb=1:17 [Violation] Avoid using document.write(). https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write
$a @ zrt_lookup.html?fsb=1:17
cb @ zrt_lookup.html?fsb=1:19
(anonymous) @ zrt_lookup.html?fsb=1:20
(anonymous) @ zrt_lookup.html?fsb=1:20
zrt_lookup.html?fsb=1:17 [Violation] Avoid using document.write(). https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write
$a @ zrt_lookup.html?fsb=1:17
cb @ zrt_lookup.html?fsb=1:19
(anonymous) @ zrt_lookup.html?fsb=1:20
(anonymous) @ zrt_lookup.html?fsb=1:20
zrt_lookup.html?fsb=1:21 [Violation] Avoid using document.write(). https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write
(anonymous) @ zrt_lookup.html?fsb=1:21
VM161541:1 [Violation] Avoid using document.write(). https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write
W @ VM161541:1
VM161569:1 [Violation] Avoid using document.write(). https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write
W @ VM161569:1
abg_lite_fy2019.js:8 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952
E @ abg_lite_fy2019.js:8
rb @ abg_lite_fy2019.js:27
xb @ abg_lite_fy2019.js:30
Gb @ abg_lite_fy2019.js:33
yb @ abg_lite_fy2019.js:32
zb @ abg_lite_fy2019.js:32
Hb @ abg_lite_fy2019.js:33
(anonymous) @ VM161574:1
(anonymous) @ zrt_lookup.html?fsb=1:21
```

Answer (score 0):

These messages are not errors, but warnings. AdSense Ads use some legacy browser APIs such as `document.write()` and non-passive event listeners which are discouraged but they still work.

Comment: "By Ad Unit" style ads do work. So, in case anyone else gets stuck, I'll mention that. Thanks,